# angular2-google-chart specify column type in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, charts

I'm trying to get the Timeline chart working from the [angular2-google-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-chart) module for Google Charts. It isn't one of the examples and this particular chart type requires a type definition for the columns--which none of the examples require. All the samples I can find are setting the type directly in JavaScript. I can't figure out how to specify the column type in TypeScript.

The error is, "Invalid data table format: column #1 must be of type 'string'."

This is the JavaScript example page: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

```
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
          [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);
```

All the angular2-google-chart examples use data like this:

```
public candle_ChartData = [
        ['Day', 'Low', 'Opening value', 'Closing value', 'High'],
        ['Mon', 28, 28, 38, 38],
        ['Tue', 38, 38, 55, 55],
        ['Wed', 55, 55, 77, 77],
        ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 66],
        ['Fri', 66, 66, 22, 22]
    ];
```

What I need is a way to specify that `'Day'` should be `'type: string, id: Day'`

It looks like this might just not be supported and I'll have to modify the directive they're supplying to add the column input. But obviously, I'd rather not spend that time if I don't have to.

https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart/blob/master/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer shortly after typing in the question. It's in the docs, I just wasn't looking in the right place.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews

Here's the required format:

```
public timeline_ChartData = [
    [ {label: 'President', id: 'President', type: 'string'}, 
      {label: 'Start', id: 'Start', type: 'date'},
      {label: 'End', id: 'End', type: 'date'}  ],
        [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3) ],
        [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 3),  new Date(1801, 2, 3) ],
        [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 3),  new Date(1809, 2, 3) ]
  ];
```